# HAproxy ACL Conditional not matching AND statement

Tags: haproxy

I'm using HAproxy 1.5.15 on Ubuntu 14.04 -- I'm attempting to add X-Frame-Options header but add an exclusion for a route `http://foo.example.com/demo/*` -- there is a page in it that is being embedded as an `iframe` on other internal sites. Per the [documentation](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#7.2) the ACL conditions "AND" should be implicit.

**ACLs**:

```
acl DEMO path_beg /demo
acl host_web hdr(Host) -i foo.example.com
```

**Does not work**:

```
rspadd X-Frame-Options:\ SAMEORIGIN unless host_web DEMO
```

**Works**:

```
rspadd X-Frame-Options:\ SAMEORIGIN unless DEMO
```

However this is flawed in that any backend now that has a route that beings with /demo will not have the X-Frame-Options header. Not a *huge* deal, but it would be nice to understand why the ACL isn't working correctly.

Comment: Try to put your `acl` in one line: `acl multiple hdr(Host) -i foo.example.com path_beg /demo`.

Comment: So, by "does not work" do you mean the header is always added even when both acls are apparently matching? Or something else?  Does `if !DEMO !host_web` also behave unexpectedly?